# if Asynctask is not for doing long background processing then what method should i use

Tags: android

I have been using Asynctask most of time, but in the current app the data downloaded is too big so what other method i can use to do background downloading, i am not actually sure whether handler are for this purpose.

Comment: you can use the handler as well bit not get the problem with Asynctask...

Comment: There is no other method rather than doinBackGround.you can show progress of downloading task using onProgressUpdate.and use more than one asynctask for independent data.

Comment: if you want you an use service as well to download data independently to your activity...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> but in the current app the data downloaded is too big so what other
>   method i can use to do background downloading,

I disagree with your title because `doInBackground` is a method that is exactly used for long tasks. So `AsyncTask` is very strong tool also type-safe.

But there is also another solution.

Another clean and efficient approach is use `IntentService` with `ResultReceiver`.

When you decide to use `IntentService` with `ResultReceiver`, here is basic example

---

Just create class that extends from `IntentService`, then you have to implement its method `onHandleIntent`

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {  
   String urlLink = intent.getStringExtra("url");
   ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
   InputStream input = null;
   long contentLength;
   long total = 0;
   int downloaded = 0;
   try {
      URL url = new URL(urlLink);
      HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      // ...
      Bundle data = new Bundle();
      data.putInt("progress", (int) (total * 100 / contentLength));
      receiver.send(PROGRESS_UPDATE, data);
   }
   //...
}
```

And implementation of `onReceiveResult` from `ResultReceiver`:

```
@Override
public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
   super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
   if (resultCode == DownloadService.PROGRESS_UPDATE) {
      int progress = resultData.getInt("progress");
      pd.setProgress(progress);
      pd.setMessage(String.valueOf(progress) + "% was downloaded sucessfully.");
   }
}
```

For start your `Service` just use

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);
i.putExtra("url", <data>); // extra additional data
i.putExtra("receiver", new DownloadReceiver(new Handler()));
startService(i);
```

So in your `IntentService` make your work and with

```
receiver.send(PROGRESS_UPDATE, data);
```

you can simply send information about your progress for update `UI`.

**Note:** But see more information about [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) nad [ResultReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html).

Answer (score 1):

Quick suggestions:

1. You can execute multiple AsyncTask if data are independent.
2. You Can take advantage of onProgressUpdate() method.